# Reference to two dimensional arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pass-by-reference

in my project i have chosen to use arrays (not dynamic). I would like to know how to relate to a two-dimensional array made in one function in another one.

Do i have to make an array in the main function and refer (and then modify in other functions) or do I do it in other way? If yes, then i would be really grateful for someone to show me, I have been searching and trying in many ways and I still have errors.
Have a great day,
Wiktoria

Comment: If the array is a local variable it will be destroyed once that function ends. That may be okay if all of the other functions are called from inside the function where it is defined, but if not you need to define the array somewhere else so it has a longer lifetime. It would be best if you could show some code that demonstrates what you're trying to do.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would [edit] your post to show the code you tried that is not working for you. Consider using `std::array` instead of raw C-style arrays.  `std::array` is easier to work with - it is easier to declare pointers/references to, it can be assigned to other `std::array`s, it can be `return`ed from functions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special syntax to pass C-Style arrays to functions.

Please see the below code

```
constexpr size_t NumberOfRows = 3;
constexpr size_t NumberOfColumns = 4;

// Typedef for easier usage
using IntMatrix2d = int[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns];

//Solution 1 ------
// Pass by reference
void function1(int(&matrix)[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns])  {}

// Pass by pointer
void function2(int(*m)[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns])  {}

//Solution 2 ------
// Pass by reference
void function3(IntMatrix2d& matrix) {}

// Pass by pointer 
void function4(IntMatrix2d* matrix) {}


int main()
{
    // Solution 1
    // Handwritten matrix. Dimension is compile time constant
    int matrix1[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns];

    // Pass by reference
    function1(matrix1);

    // Pass by pointer
    function2(&matrix1);

    // Solution 2 -----
    IntMatrix2d matrix2;

    // Pass by reference
    function3(matrix2);

    // Pass by pointer
    function4(&matrix2);

    return 0;
}
```

But basically you should use `std::array` instead-